# Trouble in returning from a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a trouble while using a javascript function in a while loop.My function executes only once.Given below is the code.

I called a function inside a while loop.That called function calls an another function.
I want to execute the first function till the end of while loop,But it executes only once.

Thanks in advance.

```
while(p<=10)
    {
        k=0;
        l=0;
        var contExp= mycontents[p].split("#");
        var divExp= mydivs[p].split(",");
        var schtime=contExp[k];
            alert(contExp[k]);
        document.getElementById('gymlocationz').value=contExp[k+1];
        document.getElementById('fitness').value=contExp[k+2];
        document.getElementById('duration').value="1 hour";
        alert(p);
        return select_visibility(divExp[l],divExp[l+1],divExp[l+2],contExp[k],mycontents[p]);
        //l=l+3;
        p++;
    }

function select_visibility(str,str1,timeid,time,cont) 
{
  var contExp= cont.split("#");
  var e = document.getElementById(str);
  var esub=document.getElementById(str+'sub');
  var fulldv=str+'sub';
  var result = timeid.match(/([0-9]+)/g);
    $('#'+str1).addClass('act');
    $('#'+str+'sub').addClass('act');
    document.getElementById(timeid).value=time;
    document.getElementById('fitness'+result).value=document.getElementById('fitness').value;
    document.getElementById('gymlocat'+result).value=document.getElementById('gymlocationz').value;
    document.getElementById('selectdrpact'+result).value=contExp[3];
    document.getElementById('repeat'+result).value=contExp[4];
    var s=document.getElementById('fitness'+result).value;
$("#"+str).css(
{
   "background-color":"#95c5ec",
   "border":"1px solid #ddd",
   "text-decoration":"none",
   "padding":"10px 0px",
   "margin-left":"30px"
});
    $("#"+fulldv).css(
    {
       "background-color":"#95c5ec",
       "border":"1px solid #ddd",
       "text-decoration":"none",
       "padding":"10px 0px",
       "margin-left":"41px"
    });
    e.style.display = 'block';
    esub.style.display = 'block'; 
    selecteditems();
    //return true;
}

function selecteditems()
{
    var i=1;
    var fld = "";
    document.getElementById("showselecteditems").innerHTML="";
    while(i<=53)
    {
    fldOne = document.getElementById('datepicker_value').value;
    fld = document.getElementById('timedrpact'+i).value;
    fidpartnum = document.getElementById('selectdrpact'+i).value;
    fidrepeat = document.getElementById('repeat'+i).value;

    fit=document.getElementById('fitness'+i).value;
    if(fit=="Select")
    {
        fit="Fitness Not Selected";
        }
    if(fld!="")
    {
            //var par='ddwnx'+i;

            //alert(fit+","+i+","+fld);
            var ele = document.createElement("div");
        ele.setAttribute("id","showselecteditems"+i);
        ele.setAttribute("class","inner");
        ele.innerHTML=fit+"&nbsp;,&nbsp;"+fldOne+"&nbsp;,&nbsp;"+fld+"&nbsp;,&nbsp;"+fidpartnum+"&nbsp;Paticipants, &nbsp;"+fidrepeat+"&nbsp;Repeat";
    }
    i++;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `return` statement inside your `while` loop. The `return` statement will cause the function to stop running and return a value to whatever code called the function. The problem is this line:

```
return select_visibility(divExp[l],divExp[l+1],divExp[l+2],contExp[k],
    mycontents[p]);
```

Change it to this:

```
select_visibility(divExp[l],divExp[l+1],divExp[l+2],contExp[k],mycontents[p]);
```

That will call the `select_visibility()` function without causing the function containing the loop to terminate.